# How can I find out where SSL Certificate is located?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I inherited a webhooks handler written in ruby using sinatra and running on an Ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) server. The SSL Certificate has expired and I need to replace it with a new one. The problem is I don't know where to put the new .crt file on the server. Is there a way to find out where it is looking for the .crt file?

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting responsibilities for old programs is a fact of life.  Try the following:

1. Read The Fine Manual, if you're lucky enough to have one.
2. Scan any invoking script for command line arguments or setup of environment variables which might locate the cert.
3. Scan the code with grep looking for .crt
4. Scan the filesystem with locate .crt and pick out the one you are looking for.
5. Bang on the program, like running it in a restricted environment, and hope an error message will complain about not finding ...

A standard approach to these problems is good, because these sort of problems wont go away.